# pulling data from mysql db where users have multiple rows but looking for the row with two maximum values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `leaders`. in it I have `id`,`userid`,`bmid`,`reps`,`rounds`,`ts`. Basically I need to put the top ten unique users out of the table that have the most `rounds`. Now each time someone enters their `reps`,`rounds` its as a pair so someone might have 12 `rounds` 13 `reps` so if that is their max and it is within the top ten of all users then I need to pull that info plus their corresponding `reps`. I thought I had this but it is actually pulling their `max` `rounds` and their `max` `reps` from different rows. What I have is below.

```
 SELECT max(l.rounds) as rounds, l.reps, m.name, l.userid 
 from leaders l 
 inner join members m on m.id = l.userid 
 where m.genre = 'male' and l.bmid  = 1 
 group by l.userid 
 order by  rounds desc,reps desc
```

the `join` is to the `members` table to get some info on them.

Comment: Sorry but what is your question?

Comment: The query I have is pulling the data with the max rounds but then its grabbing the min reps for the same user which might not go in the same row as the max reps. So basically I need to pull max rounds then use max reps as a tie breaker in case people have the same rounds then display the top ten peoples info.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need a subquery to achieve this. Take a look at this:

[How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

EDIT: Try this code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bb81/3

```
CREATE TABLE `leaders` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11),
  `rounds` int(11),
  `reps` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `leaders` (userid, rounds, reps) VALUES
  (1, 5, 3), (1, 7, 2), (1, 7, 1), (1, 7, 8),
  (2, 7, 6), (2, 7, 9), (2, 4, 3),
  (3, 7, 2), (3, 3, 5),
  (4, 8, 9);

SELECT
  userid,
  MAX(rounds) AS max_rounds, (
    SELECT MIN(reps)
    FROM leaders l2
    WHERE l2.userid = l1.userid AND l2.rounds <> l1.rounds
  ) AS min_reps
FROM leaders l1
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY max_rounds DESC, min_reps ASC;
```

Comment: Theres a bmid in there that pertains to the actual exercise that the query is filtering for. Aside from that, this query pulls up the same results, the max from one row and the min from another. I think what I might do is pull out the top ten I need for that specific exercise, put it into an array and then sort by max reps, that will make for less calls to the database as well. Thanks for trying on this, wish there was a way to do it with a query.